# Cant send SMS via firebase phone auth

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am new in Kotlin. Trying to send SMS via firebase phone auth but I get

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property callbacks has not been initialized

here is my code

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        val phoneNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneNumber)
        val loginButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.loginButton)
        loginButton.setOnClickListener {

            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber.text.toString().drop(1), // Phone number to verify
                60, // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
                this, // Activity (for callback binding)
                callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallback

            callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                    //
                }

                override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
                    //
                }


            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `val`, `lateinit var` members don't require you to initialize them when the class is instantiated.  But you will get that error if you try to use them before they are assigned.

Your code is passing `callback` as a parameter to `verifyPhoneNumber()` before its' defined in the line below.  Reorder your code to assign it first, then make use of it.